# Can you encrypt drive with BitLocker when it's formatted using ReFS?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

Can you encrypt drive with BitLocker when it's formatted using ReFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can you encrypt drive with BitLocker when it's formatted using ReFS?

Yes.

> The following features are available on ReFS and NTFS:
>
> ```
> Functionality         ReFS    NTFS
> BitLocker encryption  Yes     Yes
> ```

Source: [Resilient File System (ReFS) overview | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview)